# Creating an iPhone App in xCode, and I need to populate it with data from Microsoft SQL Server. Is this possible?

Tags: iphone, sql-server, xcode

Creating an iPhone App in xCode, and I need to populate it with data from Microsoft SQL Server. Is this possible? If so, are there any tutorials online that can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend going for a 3 layer model.

- Your database
- A webservice , that fetches data from the database when your app sends a request to the   webservice
- Your App, that connects to the webservice and requests data from the webservice, which in turn connects to the database.

Why this complicated? Because if you connect to your database directly in your iPhone app without a webservice between it. (if that is even possible in iPhone apps) then you are running a security risk because your app will contain your database connection string.

Comment: If you use PHP, it contains the database connection. You wold simply set your URL to myexample.com/get_db_info.php and that php file would contain the connection information and return the data needed. The DB connection information never leaves the server, and it is never stored in your app. NSURLConnection is essentially the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is very possible. [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) is a great start for using NSURLConnection, and then you should look up NSJSONSerialization or XML parsing to handle the data. Basically you will need a .php file on your server, that you can use to query MySQL and return the format you like.

There are many tutorials out there, and some great YouTube videos on JSON or XML parsing from databases.

For TableView populating and asynchronous downloading, Apple has sample code by the name of LazyTableView.

This site is also full of examples.

Comment: Great answer :) I don't usually use SQLServer (or a PC, to be frank), but I have a client who is adamant on storing his data using MS SQL Server. If I had a better understanding of the program itself, this wouldn't be so difficult. Follow up question: Does SQL Server manage LOCAL data (e.g. stored on a hard drive), or does it manage data in an online database?

Comment: MySQL is a database language. There are others like Oracle etc. It runs on a server (or desktop/laptop, really wherever you install it) and it stores tables of information. You query the server based on table name and and ask for information you want. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/tutorial.html A great getting started tutorial. Remember to check the answer you use!

Comment: I'm totally familiar with MySQL (I'm a big Drupal user); but is Microsoft SQL Server (the program) something different than your typical MySQL database (hosted on a domain)? Just trying to figure out what that program is used for :) E.g. If someone is using MS SQL Server to manage a database, it MUST be hosted on a domain, correct?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. No you can install MS SQL on any machine. We have it running in our office on many small, off domain machines.

Comment: Ok, that's the part that's confusing me. If MS SQL is managing a database on a PC, wouldn't that database have to be exported to a host/domain before it can be accessed via xCode for an iPhone app?

Comment: You can open ports and use the IP address where your server is hosted in xcode. Otherwise yes, it would be a good idea to point a domain name at your public IP address and then use DNS to access the server. You will need to make sure that port 80 is forwarded to your server and that apache/iis are listening.

Comment: Ooooh I get it. This makes sense. THANK YOU. You've been super helpful =)